# Google Colab can't Extract a big file saved in my Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, unzip, unrar

I am trying to Extract a big file saved in Google Drive into itself. I tried Google Drive apps in Google Workspace Marketplace like "ZIP Extractor" and "UnRAR and RAR viewer", But due to being a large file, they become Not Responding... Then I tried python packages called "unrarfile" and "pyunpack" in google colab which is connected to my Google Drive. This time the extracting process runs very well and but after finishing the extracting, I see a few first files have been saved in google Drive but the rest doesn't. I tried splitting the big .rar file to smaller files but the problem still exists.

I'll appreciate if anyone have encountered the same problem and has a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Google colab is a free research product from Google. Because of this reason the resources are also limited.

There is quota limit above which contents from drive cant be unzipped. This quota fluctuates daily and is not fixed.

From your above problem I guess you have reached your quota for today and have to wait till tomorrow till it resets.

But keep in mind that since your file is very large you cant unzip the whole file in colab at any point.

Colab is not really a place for large projects. One solution is to go to paperspace and activate a paid account to have unlimited data storage and GPU facilities.

For more doubts check out this [colab faq page](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was not familiar with quota limitations on google Drive. I think "quota limits" prevent google colab from writing so many files on my Google Drive per day. So, I'm searching for ways to directly read my data from .rar files instead of extracting and then reading them. Thanks again.